# MySQL - I have foreign key, but I don't set it as a foreign key in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

I have foreign key, but I don't set it as a foreign key in phpmyadmin. it just a INTEGER type column.
Question : What is the difference result between setting or not setting it as foreign key in phpmyadmin?

Comment: MySQL makes some checks for foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FOREIGN KEY` constraint enables some automatic checks by the database engine.

If you don't specify it as a foreign key, you won't get an error if you try to insert a value that doesn't exist in the other table. And you can't make use of options like `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which automatically deletes the row in the child table if the parent row is deleted.